# Entity Framework one to one relation, disconnected entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to work with disconnected objects. In my model a user can have or not an address.

First my model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base()
    {
    }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BornDate { get; set; }
    public virtual SubscriptionSetting SubscriptionSetting { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; private set; }

    public void AddAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public Address(string id, string number, string type, string nom, string postalCode, string city, GPSCoordinates gps)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Number = number;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Nom = nom;
        this.PostalCode = postalCode;
        this.City = city;
        this.GPSCoordinates = gps;
    }

    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nom { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual GPSCoordinates GPSCoordinates { get; set; }
}
```

My context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubscriptionSettingConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My configuration:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserConfiguration() : base()
    {
        HasRequired(u => u.Address).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        Property(u => u.BornDate).HasColumnType("datetime2");
    }
}

public class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        HasKey(m => m.Id);
    }
}
```

And my repo:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
{
        DbSet.Add(entity);

        try
        {
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());

                foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
            }

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(
                "Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:\n" +
                sb.ToString(), ex
            );
        }

        return entity;
}
```

Finally my unit test :

```
public class adress_repository_test
{
    IRepository<Address> _addressRepository;
    DbContext _context;

    public adress_repository_test()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _addressRepository = new Repository<Address>(_context);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task insert_new_address_success()
    {
        GPSCoordinates gps = new GPSCoordinates(44.5, 41.2);
        Address address = new Address("d0ead995-ca31-4950-bfd3-93e0ca82e37e", "BATC", "Allée", "beethoven", "60100", "creil", gps);
        var result = await _addressRepository.InsertAsync(address);
        Assert.NotEmpty(address.Id);
    }
```

When the test run it throws an exception :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Address'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Address'. The duplicate key value is
>   (d0ead995-ca31-4950-bfd3-93e0ca82e37e)

Comment: How are you cleaning up the prior test run? Looks like your test record is already in the database. There are a number of techniques for reseting the database (transactions, tear down delete, etc.) or you could simply do if (_addressRepository.Find(id)) _addressRepository.Delete(id) before you try to add.

Comment: Thank you Steve. But i can't accepte your response. In my table Address, there is no row. That's why i ask this question. Table aspnetuser and table Address has one - one relation. There is one row in the table aspnetuser, then i want to add an address to my user. The table address has one primary foreign key which is the primary key of the table aspnetuser.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question but i haven't becareful about the config of my test, the connexion string is not present, and it's create a new database .
Steve is right the row is present in the BDD